# jq- merge two json files on a value

Tags: json, join, jq

i have two json files structured like that:

file 1

```
[
{
    "id": 25422,
    "location": "Hotel X",
    "suppliers": [
        12
    ]
},
{
    "id": 25423,
    "location": "Hotel Y",
    "suppliers": [
        13
    ]
}]
```

file 2

```
[
{
    "id": 12,
    "vatNumber": "0000000000"
},
{
    "id": 14,
    "vatNumber": "0000000001"
}]
```

and i'd like a result like this

```
[
{
    "id": 25422,
    "location": "Hotel X",
    "suppliers": [
        12
    ],
    "vatNumber": "0000000000"
},
{
    "id": 25423,
    "location": "Hotel Y",
    "suppliers": [
        13
    ],
}]
```

The important thing to me is that the matching vatNumbers, are set in the first file. Supplier arrays are not required anymore after the melding, if it simplifies the job.
Also jq is not essential, but i need something i can use via terminal to set up a script.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can the `suppliers` array contain multiple elements? If so, what `vatNumber` should be output?

Comment: @Aaron the supplier array contains only one parameter, that is what i've seen so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one of many possible solutions.  If your jq does not have `INDEX/2`, then either upgrade your jq or include its def (available e.g. from https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq):

Invocation:

```
jq -n --argfile f1 file1.json --argfile f2 file2.json -f merge.jq
```

merge.jq:

```
INDEX($f2[] ; .id) as $dict
| $f1
| map( ($dict[.suppliers[0]|tostring]|.vatNumber) as $vn
       | if $vn then .vatNumber = $vn else . end)
```